# Puppet Standalone Configuration

Tags: centos, puppet

Is it possible, when running Puppet as standalone to keep it from attempting to contact the default server?

It's not the end of the world but every two minutes it's adding a line to my /var/log/messages file saying it can't connect to it.

I wasn't able to find anything in the puppet docs or by googling.

Comment: What do you mean by *standalone*? If you don't want Puppet to reach out to the Puppetmaster, you can stop the daemon.

Comment: And that was a "well duuuuh" moment.  I appreciate it @ewwhite.

Comment: or better, in your pp file put a service resource with ensure => stopped, enabled => false for that daemon.

Answer (score 1):

this is as simple as

```
puppet apply --verbose my_manifests.pp
```